# WPF prevent TreeViewItem to inherit contextMenu from parent by code

Tags: wpf, treeview, contextmenu

I have the following code and I set explicite the ContextMenu from a TreeViewItem to null but it shows all the time the same ContextMenu as the treeviewitem parents! Is that a bug? and how can I solve that?

```
        Tree.Items.Clear();
        System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem ceo = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem() { Header = "CEO" };
        System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem manager1 = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem() { Header = "Manager1" };
        System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem manager2 = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem() { Header = "Manager2" };
        System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem person1 = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem() { Header = "person1" };
        System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem person2 = new System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem() { Header = "person2" };

        manager1.Items.Add(person1);
        manager2.Items.Add(person2);
        ceo.Items.Add(manager1);
        ceo.Items.Add(manager2);
        Tree.Items.Add(ceo);

        // context Menu
        MenuItem menu1 = new MenuItem();
        menu1.Header = "Menu1";
        MenuItem menu2 = new MenuItem();
        menu2.Header = "Menu2";
        MenuItem menu3 = new MenuItem();
        menu3.Header = "Menu3";
        MenuItem menu4 = new MenuItem();
        menu4.Header = "Menu4";
        MenuItem menu5 = new MenuItem();
        menu5.Header = "Menu5";
        MenuItem menu6 = new MenuItem();
        menu6.Header = "Menu6";


        System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu ceoMenu = new ContextMenu();
        ceoMenu.Items.Add(menu1);
        ceoMenu.Items.Add(menu2);
        ceoMenu.Items.Add(menu3);

        System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu managerMenu = new ContextMenu();
        managerMenu.Items.Add(menu4);
        managerMenu.Items.Add(menu5);

        ceo.ContextMenu = ceoMenu;
        manager1.ContextMenu = managerMenu;
        manager2.ContextMenu = managerMenu;

        System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu personMenu = new ContextMenu();
        personMenu.Items.Add(menu6);

        person1.ContextMenu = personMenu;
        person2.ContextMenu = null;
```

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 2):

It works fine to set it like:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu nullMenu = new ContextMenu();
        nullMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

        person1.ContextMenu = personMenu;
        person2.ContextMenu = nullMenu;
```

Comment: `<ContextMenu x:Key="nullMenu" Visibility="Hidden">
    <!--Used for hiding unwanted popup-->
</ContextMenu>`. This is the an equivalent XAML code. Now use it like, for example `<Label Content="{Binding TagName}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource nullMenu}" />`

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. If you set breakpoint on ContextMenuOpening event for person2, you will see, that it doesn't fired at all.
After that you can try to set breakpoint on ContextMenuOpening event for manager2. It's fired and on person2 node, but only because TreeViewItem is ItemsControl.
In WPF Visualizer we can see that:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's not a bug. It is logical behavior. For example, if user clicks at the column at DataGrid, then it always shows the same ContextMenu. So if you set `ContextMenu` to `null`, then it just replaces your context menu by base context menu.

So we can make a little trick. We just change state of visibility of your ContextMenu.

So to have the personal `Visibility` of `ContextMenu`,  you should just create another state of `Visibility`(`Hidden`, `Visible` or `Collapse`) to your created `ContextMenu`.

```
System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu personMenu = new ContextMenu();
personMenu.Items.Add(menu6);
personMenu.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
person1TVI.ContextMenu = personMenu;            
person2TVI.ContextMenu = personMenu;
```

Comment: @user5514770 if my answer helps to your question, you can mark it as an answer to simplify search by other people